# Как сделать AddForce к некой точке? Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в Unity сделать так, чтобы Rigidbody двигалось к заданным координатам с заданной силой? Как MoveTo, но с возможностью задать силу движения?

AddForce.forward + поворот не подойдет, т.к. тело нужно сначала повернуть, а в данном случае не вариант.

Comment: Господа минусующие, объясните причину хотя бы. Вопрос неточно сформулирован, требуются дополнительные разъяснения или слишком часто встречается? 
Подобный вопрос я встретил лишь в англоязычном варианте. 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/444761/move-rigidbody-to-a-specific-position.html
Решение, предоставленное там у меня не работает. 
Прокомментируйте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё оказалось довольно просто.

Вариант из англоязычного источника не подходил, поскольку был предназначен для скрипта, который крепился на двигаемый предмет. Отсюда и использование `transform.position`.

В моем случае управляющий скрипт висит на другом объекте.

Поэтому скрипт выглядит следующим образом.

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.CompareTag("fishka"))
        {

            Collider col = hit.collider;
            var dir = (hit.point - col.transform.position); // Используем координаты коллайдера
            rot.z = hit.point.z;
            rot.x = hit.point.x;

            col.attachedRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(dir.x, 0, dir.z) * speed;

            Debug.Log(hit.point + " hitpoint");
            Debug.Log(transform.position + " transform.position");
```